# Mirror an image using Pure Javascript/JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, mirror

Due to device restriction, I had to use only javascript or JQuery to "Mirror" an image.
I had tried Reflection.js but that is not I want.

What I want is to simply "mirror" the img tag's image.

Anyone can help ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: My gut is to assume the answer is no, but can you rely on an HTML5 canvas or would that break the device restriction?

Comment: This looks like a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8168217/html-canvas-how-to-draw-a-flipped-mirrored-image

Comment: What's the device? If it supports css3 (ie. webkit) then it's simple, no JS needed, http://jsbin.com/ugecus/1/edit

Comment: I tried CSS3 but it won't work on my device.
My boss mention about not using HTML5 for my project.

Comment: Should be possible in IE using DX filters, and I believe in Firefox using SVG filters.  Not sure if your device supports either.

Answer (score 3):

Try this example mention in jsfiddle :

**CSS :**

```
div.reflection
{
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(-1);
    -moz-transform: scaleY(-1);
    -o-transform: scaleY(-1);
    -ms-transform: scaleY(-1);
    transform: scaleY(-1);
}

img{
    height: 150px;
    width: 150px;
}
```

**HTML Code :**

```
<div>
    <img src='http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-TslgI6ySuW8/VNC-u9YQYeI/AAAAAAAABtA/mviMstL4pIk/s1600/Screenshot_2015-02-03-17-55-46.png'/>
</div>
<div class="reflection">
    <img src='http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-TslgI6ySuW8/VNC-u9YQYeI/AAAAAAAABtA/mviMstL4pIk/s1600/Screenshot_2015-02-03-17-55-46.png'/>
</div>
```

[Click here](http://jsfiddle.net/pFRXS/128/)