# get image's mirror image using jquery

Tags: jquery, image, mirror

I want to get mirror image of image in both x-axis and y-axis using jQuery . When user clicks on button image changes to it's mirror image.

I am not able to search it on internet.

I just got [one solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15149236/mirror-an-image-using-pure-javascript-jquery) using css not jquery but I need jQuery for both the direction.

I want to do these reflections one by one means when I click on Reflect X button it should reflect on X-axis and similar case for Y axis.

So I used scaleX(-1) instead of scale() for x-axis but what the problem is When I do it image is reflecting fine but it's position is changing. Can you Please help me to keep it stay on the same place and just reflect it on x-axis.

Thanks!!!

Comment: You could action the css solution using Jquery? Jquery can manipulate CSS.

Answer (score 6):

You can use CSS3 to mirror the image

```
-moz-transform: scale(-1, 1);
-webkit-transform: scale(-1, 1);
transform: scale(-1, 1);
```

To use this with jQuery, you could do something like this:

```
 .mirror {
     -moz-transform: scale(-1, 1);
     -webkit-transform: scale(-1, 1);
     transform: scale(-1, 1);
  }
```

And then add the class "mirror" to the Object.

```
$('object').addClass('mirror');
```

to make it back normal, just remove it:

```
 $('object').removeClass('mirror');
```

Comment: Thanks @Simon I got it how to do with jQuery.

Comment: Glad I could help. If your question has been answered, don't forget to select an answer as the best.

Comment: I want to do these reflections one by one means when I click on Reflect X button it should reflect on X-axis and similar case for Y axis. So I used scaleX(-1) instead of scale() for x-axis but what the problem is When I do it image is reflecting fine but it's position is changing. Can you Please help me to keep it stay on the same place and just reflect it on x-axis. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can use CSS for this.

```
transform: scale(-1, -1)
```

This will set both X and Y to -1.

The first one is X and the second is Y.

From MozDev:

```
transform:  scale(sx[, sy]);     /* one or two unitless <number>s, e.g.  scale(2.1,4) */
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/transform