# How to horizontally flip an image

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

How can i draw only two images with reversing **I don't know how to reverse**. Pls help.

```
    var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    canvas.width = 16 * scale;
    canvas.height = 32 * scale;
    //we assign the same classname the image has, for CSS purposes
    canvas.setAttribute('class', skinImage.getAttribute('class'));
    canvas.setAttribute('title', skinImage.getAttribute('title'));
    var context = canvas.getContext("2d"),
    s = scale;
    context.imageSmoothingEnabled=!1,
    context.mozImageSmoothingEnabled=!1,
    context.oImageSmoothingEnabled=!1,
    CanvasRenderingContext2D.webkitImageSmoothingEnabled=!1,
    context.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);

    //back draw the head
    context.drawImage(skinImage, 24,  8,  8, 8,  4*s,  0*s,  8*s, 8*s);
    //back draw the body
    context.drawImage(skinImage, 32, 20, 8, 12, 4*s,  8*s,  8*s, 12*s);
    //back draw the right leg
    context.drawImage(skinImage, 52, 20, 4, 12, 12*s, 8*s,  4*s, 12*s);
    //back draw the right arm
    context.drawImage(skinImage, 12, 20, 4, 12, 8*s,  20*s, 4*s, 12*s);

    //back draw the left arm
    context.drawImage(skinImage, 12, 20, 4, 12, 4*s,  20*s, 4*s, 12*s);
    context.drawImage(skinImage, 52, 20, 4, 12, 0*s,  8*s,  4*s, 12*s);
```

Comment: why don't we use css? `transform: scaleX(-1);`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First, to remove your 2 unwanted image, just clear the canvas and redraw the desired images. You can clear the canvas using `context.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height)`.

**Flip image(s) horizontally**

[image]

**How to horizontally flip an image:**

1. Move (translate) the canvas origin to your desired X-coordinate plus the image width: `context.translate(x + img.width, y);` Adding the img.width is necessary because we are grabbing the left edge of the image and flipping it leftward. Without adding img.width, the img would be drawn leftward of the desired x-coordinate.
2. Flip horizontally using `context.scale(-1, 1);`
3. Draw the image: `context.drawImage(img, 0, 0);`
4. Clean up by resetting transformations to their default values: `context.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);`

**Annotated code and a Demo:**

```js
var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
var cw=canvas.width;
var ch=canvas.height;

var img=new Image();
img.onload=start;
img.src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/multple/sillouette2.png";
function start(){

    ctx.fillText('original',10,30);
    ctx.drawImage(img,10,30);

    ctx.fillText('flipped',150,30);
    flipHorizontally(img,150,30);

}

function flipHorizontally(img,x,y){
    // move to x + img's width
    ctx.translate(x+img.width,y);

    // scaleX by -1; this "trick" flips horizontally
    ctx.scale(-1,1);
    
    // draw the img
    // no need for x,y since we've already translated
    ctx.drawImage(img,0,0);
    
    // always clean up -- reset transformations to default
    ctx.setTransform(1,0,0,1,0,0);
}
```

```css
#canvas{border:1px solid red; margin:0 auto; }
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=300></canvas>
```

**[Addition: flipping a sprite from a spritesheet]**

To flip a sprite that's contained in a spritesheet you can use the cropping form of `drawImage`. The cropping drawImage will crop the desired sprite from the spritesheet by specifiying the sprite's `spriteX, spriteY, spriteWidth & spriteHeight`. The same cropping drawImage will also draw the cropped sub-image onto the canvas by specifying the desire canvas `canvasX, canvasY, spriteWidth & spriteHeight`.

**Here is code showing how to flip a sprite from a spritesheet**

```js
var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
var cw=canvas.width;
var ch=canvas.height;

var img=new Image();
img.onload=start;
img.src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/multple/cars.jpg";
function start(){

  var spriteX=92;
  var spriteY=63;
  var spriteW=80;
  var spriteH=40;

  ctx.fillText('original',10,30);
  ctx.drawImage(img,spriteX,spriteY,spriteW,spriteH,10,30,spriteW,spriteH);

  ctx.fillText('flipped',150,30);
  flipSpriteHorizontally(img,150,30, spriteX,spriteY,spriteW,spriteH);

}

function flipSpriteHorizontally(img,x,y,spriteX,spriteY,spriteW,spriteH){
  // move to x + img's width
  // adding img.width is necessary because we're flipping from
  //     the right side of the img so after flipping it's still
  //     at [x,y]
  ctx.translate(x+spriteW,y);

  // scaleX by -1; this "trick" flips horizontally
  ctx.scale(-1,1);

  // draw the img
  // no need for x,y since we've already translated
  ctx.drawImage(img,
                spriteX,spriteY,spriteW,spriteH,0,0,spriteW,spriteH
               );

  // always clean up -- reset transformations to default
  ctx.setTransform(1,0,0,1,0,0);
}
```

```css
#canvas{border:1px solid red; margin:0 auto; }
```

```html
<h4>Drawing & horizontally flipping a sprite</h4>
<canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=100></canvas>
<h4>Spritesheet:</h4>
<img src='https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/multple/cars.jpg'>
```

Comment: it hides my images what should i do ?

Comment: Your question is unclear. Please take time to make your question more clear using the **edit** button under your question. ;-) I (might) understand from your [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35972416/canvas-javascript-drawimage-reversing) that you are drawing many images and you want to remove 2 of them. The typical method is to clear the canvas completely (`context.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height`) and then redraw only those images that you still want to appear.

Comment: oh sorry im not trying to remove 2 of them i have 6 images in one canvas and i want to reverse(mirror) 2 of them im tried scale and set transform but both of them hiding my 2 images

Comment: im sorry for my bad english :(

Comment: @TrkeRap. It's ok :-) -- We just need more information. Are you trying to flip the image horizontally? Meaning if a face image starts out looking right then you want to redraw that same face looking left? Or something else?

Comment: Yes exactly i want that

Comment: @TrkeRap I've changed my answer to show how to remove your 2 unwanted images and how to horizontally flip any image.

Comment: its worked but it shows all of image that i draw but i want only one area in the image ex(from12,to20) what should i do ?

Comment: if i use translate it flips all the image i tried without translate but it becomes hidden

Comment: @TrkeRap: To draw just 1 sprite from a spritesheet you can use the cropping form of `drawImage` to display just the desired sprite. I've added a code and demo showing how to do it. Good luck with your project!

Comment: oh its work but how i will set the canvas destination where the image will drawn in canvas ?

Comment: oh i fixed it tank you again for your help

Answer (score 4):

### Mirror an image

Here is a simple utility function that will mirror an image horizontally, vertically or both.

```
// arguments
// ctx : the context on which to draw the mirrored image
// image : the image to mirror
// x,y : the top left of the rendered image
// horizontal : boolean if true mirror along X
// vertical : boolean if true mirror along y
function mirrorImage(ctx, image, x = 0, y = 0, horizontal = false, vertical = false){
    ctx.save();  // save the current canvas state
    ctx.setTransform(
        horizontal ? -1 : 1, 0, // set the direction of x axis
        0, vertical ? -1 : 1,   // set the direction of y axis
        x + horizontal ? image.width : 0, // set the x origin
        y + vertical ? image.height : 0   // set the y origin
    );
    ctx.drawImage(image,0,0);
    ctx.restore(); // restore the state as it was when this function was called
}
```

Usage

```
mirrorImage(ctx, image, 0, 0, true, false); // horizontal mirror
mirrorImage(ctx, image, 0, 0, false, true); // vertical mirror
mirrorImage(ctx, image, 0, 0, true, true);  // horizontal and vertical mirror
```

#### More mirrors

If you wish to be able to mirror along an arbitrary line see the answer [Mirror along line](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42512939/3877726)

Comment: Amazing! Thanks! I was looking for this! :)

Answer (score 0):

To mirror image you can use `setTransform` with negative scale.

```
context.setTransform(-1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);    //Now all images will be horizontally mirrored
context.drawImage(<myimage>, srcx, srcy, srcw, srch, dstx, dsty, dstw, dsth);
```

Don't forget to restore transform when you finished.

```
context.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);
```

Comment: Read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8168217/html-canvas-how-to-draw-a-flipped-mirrored-image

Answer (score 0):

```
function mirrorImage(image, src_x, src_y, img_width, img_height, x, y){

   // 1. MIRROR THE CONTEXT
   context.scale(-1, 1);

   // 2. DRAW IN CANVAS USING (-X - img_width)
   context.drawImage(image, src_x, src_y, img_width, img_height, - 
   x - img_width, y, img_width, img_height);

   // 3. RETURN CONTEXT TO ORIGINAL STATE (AFTER DRAWING)
   context.scale(-1, 1);

}
```