# Can't seem to get ctx.slale(-1,1) to work in HTML5 canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas, drawing, scaletransform

I am trying to create a mirror image transformation (and later an angled transformation) of dynamically generated group of lines in canvas. I'm attempting to do so by flipping the canvas and drawing a symmetrical line at each step, like so:

- Generate random variables
- Draw line

  `ctx.save();`

  `ctx.scale(-1,1);`
- Draw line in flipped context

  `ctx. restore();`

I don't think the context is flipping appropriately because if I set scale values to, say, -5 and 5 they thicken my lines without flipping them.

Full attempt: http://codepen.io/RadaCodes/pen/RKQOXW?editors=1010

Please suggest what I'm doing wrong. Thank you.

Comment: You need to `translate()` your matrix in the opposite direction : `ctx.scale(-1,1);
  ctx.translate(-ctx.canvas.width,0)`  http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KaoXmo?editors=1010

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to horizontally flip an image](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35973441/how-to-horizontally-flip-an-image)

Comment: Thank you so much Kaiido, this does it. Cheeers.