# Drawing an image from right to left in html5 canvas context

Tags: javascript, animation, html5-canvas, transform

I need context.drawImage(...) begins drawing from right to left. It is possible to do this?
Lets say I have player1 and player2 as in the pictures

[image: player2]    [image: player2]

The thing is both of them are same sprite, and each frame of that sprite has different width and height, which is not a problem when i draw player1(left align) because the variation of width can affect the rightmost part of the arm, but not the movement of the character. Now, when I draw player1 fliped(player2), the painting begins for the punching hand and that messes the character movement animation. So, what i want is drawing player2 beginning for the right side of the image instead the default method, or any viable solution.
My sprite painter  is this

```
that.paint=function(frameOriginX,frameOriginY,xPosition,yPosition,frameWidth,frameHeight,previousWidth,previousHeight,fliped){
      if(fliped==true){
    that.context.imageSmoothingEnabled = false; 
    that.context.save();
    that.context.translate(xPosition, yPosition + frameHeight);
    that.context.rotate(180*Math.PI/180);
    that.context.scale(1, -1);
    that.context.translate(-(xPosition + frameWidth), -(yPosition + frameHeight));
   }
   //floor var is global and is equal to 300
   var oldYCoord=floor-previousHeight;
   that.context.clearRect(xPosition,oldYCoord, previousWidth, previousHeight);       
       that.context.drawImage(
       that.image,
       frameOriginX,
       frameOriginY,
       frameWidth,
       frameHeight,
       xPosition,
       yPosition,
       frameWidth,
       frameHeight);
   if(fliped==true)
    that.context.restore();
}
```

For learning reasons I am using plain javascript for the job, no engines no librarys. Here is the [game demo](https://github.com/kanonhian/mk-demo)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8168217/html-canvas-how-to-draw-a-flipped-mirrored-image

Comment: does not solve the problem really. With this indeed the sprite is fliped, but still drawing from the border of the arm to the back and i need the opposite. I updated the answer with a link to code, take a look if possible.