# Mirror a shape from HTML5 canvas using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, canvas, html5-canvas

I have this shape that I have made on my HTML canvas, so basically what I want to do is that I want to mirror the shape and move it to a different part of the canvas. I have tried `folds.scale(-1,1);` but it does not work. I have viewed this other post about mirroring shapes but my code somehow doesn't work.

[HTML Canvas: How to draw a flipped/mirrored image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8168217/html-canvas-how-to-draw-a-flipped-mirrored-image)

This is my code:

```
function folds(x, y ,z){
    draw.beginPath();
    draw.arc(x, y, z, 5.25, 2 * Math.PI);
    draw.closePath();
    draw.lineWidth = 7;
    draw.strokeStyle = "black";
    draw.stroke();
}

function folds2(){
    folds.scale(-1,1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The most popular solution is to create another invisible canvas in your HTML and transform its horizontal dimensions backwards:

```
const flippedCanvas = document.getElementById("flipped-canvas");
const flippedContext = canvas.getContext("2d");

flippedContext.scale(-1, 1);
```

Then, you can draw an image (or shape) on that canvas and copy it to your original canvas using [drawImage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/drawImage):

```
flippedContext.beginPath();
// ...
flippedContext.stroke();
draw.drawImage(flippedCanvas, 0, 0);
```